# android SQLite query on multiple columns

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to query my `SQLite` table and limit the results to show only the records that match my criteria.

I want to filter the results where `COLOR="red"` and `CLASS="alpha"`

Here is what I have so far which results in a `NULLPointerException` on the query:

```
    public Cursor getDetailRecords( String color, String category ) {

    final String SELECTION = KEY_COLOR + "=?" + " and " + KEY_CLASS + "=?";
    final String[] SELECTION_ARGS = { color, category };

    Cursor mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, DATABASE_STRUCTURE, 
            SELECTION, SELECTION_ARGS, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

I'm using category for my variable instead of class which is a reserved word.

I'm not sure how to format my selection `string`.  Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have " on color and category? Kan you provide the stacktrace?

Comment: if you are getting nullpointerexception then maybe db is null. have you initialized it?

Comment: nandeesh - you are spot on.  I had created an instance of my dbAdapter but I had neglected to issue a db.open() command.  Thanks for your help.  If you put your suggestion as an answer, I will accept it.